# Why did two meanings of the term non-parametric arise?

Tags: nonparametric

There are two meanings for non-parametric:

1. Non-fixed number of parameters
2. Distribution-free assumptions

How did this happen? Was it due to two communities diverging? It is sometimes confusing to know which one is being used.

Comment: Can you give a reference to 1) ?

Comment: There are often infinitely many meanings to "not-X" where "X" is some specifically defined property.  What temperature is "not boiling"?  What height is "not six feet"?